# How to get a sorted list of most used values for a field in a mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents resembling the following structure:

```
{ 
   "name": "item_1",
   "category": ["a", "b"]
},
{ 
   "name": "item_2",
   "category": ["c"]
},
{ 
   "name": "item_3",
   "category": ["a", "c"]
},
{ 
   "name": "item_4",
   "category": ["a"]
},
{ 
   "name": "item_5",
   "category": ["a"]
}
```

I'm trying to get a sorted list of the most used values for the category field in all documents within the collection.

So in this example, the return value I'm expecting should be something like this:

```
[
   {
      "category": "a",
      "count": 4
   },
   {
      "category": "c",
      "count": 2
   },
   {
      "category": "b",
      "count": 1
   }
]
```

Is there a way to make such a query in mongoose?

Comment: You will have to use aggregation for this.are you looking for a aggregation solution, I would recommend read the documentation and try some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/sBpwwvowXLH

Use aggregation query to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your category into separate documents [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them back by category and get the count

[$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$category"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$category",
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Just had to add $sort: { count: -1 } after $group to get the result sorted by count